# validating char user input loop

Tags: java, string

I'm writing a simple calculator program, the user inputs two integers and a symbol (`+` `-` `*` etc) which represents the operation (add, subtract, multiply, etc) to be applied to the integers and the program calculates what they asked.

I have a `do-while` loop to continually ask for input if the input does not match the given symbols.

I've tried comparing them but I'm unsuccessful and very uncertain on what to do

CODE:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

int num1, num2, sum, difference, product;

String a, b, c, userInput;

char choice, plus, minus, times;

System.out.print(First Integer: --> ");
num1 = scan.nextInt();

System.out.print(Second Integer: --> ");
num2 = scan.nextInt();

a = "+";
b = "-";
c = "*";

plus = a.charAt(0);
minus = b.charAt(0);
times = c.charAt(0);

do {
    System.out.print("Choose + - or *");
    userInput = scan.Next();

    choice = userInput.charAt(0);
} while(choice != '+' || choice != '-' || choice != '*');

switch(choice) {
     case 1:
     sum = num1 + num2;
     System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
     break;

     case 2:
     difference = num1 - num2;
     System.out.println("Difference is " + difference);
     break;

     case 3:
     product = num1 ' num2;
     System.out.println("Product is " + product);
     break;
}
```

Comment: Start by inserting  `'` marks and changing `||` for `&&` in `while(choice != '+' && choice != '-' && choice != '*')`

Comment: It is a good idea to always paste the errors or exception stack traces you get into the question (as text).

Answer (score 2):

There were some errors in your code, I have tried to rectify them.
Take a look,

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int num1, num2, sum, difference, product;
        String userInput;
        char choice, plus, minus, times;

        System.out.println("First Integer: --> ") ;
        num1 = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Second Integer: --> ") ;
        num2 = scan.nextInt();

        plus = '+';
        minus = '-';
        times = '*';

        do {
        System.out.println("Choose + - or *") ;
        userInput = scan.next();
        choice = userInput.charAt(0);
            
        }while(choice != '+' && choice != '-' && choice != '*');
        
        switch(choice) {
            case '+':
            sum = num1 + num2;
            System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
            break;

            case '-':
            difference = num1 - num2;
            System.out.println("Difference is " + difference);
            break;

            case '*':
            product = num1 * num2;
            System.out.println("Product is " + product);
            break;
                 
            default :
                 System.out.println("Wrong Choice!");
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer for the same. @DawoodibnKareem

Comment: This is very helpful! However I noticed that when I entered - the first time it told me it was wrong, however when I entered it again it worked? I'm guessing it worked since the second prompt was in the loop unlike the first.